# R: Converting data from long to wide format

Tags: r

I've the following data in long format.

```
MVal    Poly    Subclass
29.44   Mono    G
29.39   Mono    G
26.11   Mono    G
24.21   Mono    F
26.60   Mono    F
28.32   Mono    F
32.28   Mono    R
31.91   Mono    R
33.58   Mono    R
25.00   Mono    E
26.64   Mono    E
23.67   Mono    E
25.20   Mono    P
26.44   Mono    P
23.87   Mono    P
21.21   Di  G
19.30   Di  G
21.97   Di  G
21.79   Di  F
18.16   Di  F
20.30   Di  F
```

How  I can  convert it to the following wide format using R? I've tried dcast(), reshape() but without success

```
Poly    Subclass MVal_1 Mval_2  MVal_3
Mono    G   29.44   29.39   26.11
Mono    F   24.21   26.60   28.32
Mono    R   32.28   31.91   33.58
Di      G   21.21   19.30   21.97
.....
.....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`s `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(nm = consecutive_id(Subclass)) %>% 
  mutate(nm = row_number(), .by = nm) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=nm, values_from=MVal, names_prefix="MVal_")
# A tibble: 7 × 5
  Poly  Subclass MVal_1 MVal_2 MVal_3
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mono  G          29.4   29.4   26.1
2 Mono  F          24.2   26.6   28.3
3 Mono  R          32.3   31.9   33.6
4 Mono  E          25     26.6   23.7
5 Mono  P          25.2   26.4   23.9
6 Di    G          21.2   19.3   22.0
7 Di    F          21.8   18.2   20.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using `dplyr>=1.10`

```
df %>%     
  summarise(MVal=list(MVal),.by=c(Poly, Subclass)) %>%
  unnest_wider(MVal, names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 7 × 5
  Poly  Subclass MVal_1 MVal_2 MVal_3
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mono  G          29.4   29.4   26.1
2 Mono  F          24.2   26.6   28.3
3 Mono  R          32.3   31.9   33.6
4 Mono  E          25     26.6   23.7
5 Mono  P          25.2   26.4   23.9
6 Di    G          21.2   19.3   22.0
7 Di    F          21.8   18.2   20.3

unnest_wider(aggregate(MVal~., df, list), MVal, names_sep='_')

# A tibble: 7 × 5
  Poly  Subclass MVal_1 MVal_2 MVal_3
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Mono  E          25     26.6   23.7
2 Di    F          21.8   18.2   20.3
3 Mono  F          24.2   26.6   28.3
4 Di    G          21.2   19.3   22.0
5 Mono  G          29.4   29.4   26.1
6 Mono  P          25.2   26.4   23.9
7 Mono  R          32.3   31.9   33.6

library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Poly+Subclass~rowidv(df[, -1]), value.var = 'MVal')
   Poly Subclass     1     2     3
1:   Di        F 21.79 18.16 20.30
2:   Di        G 21.21 19.30 21.97
3: Mono        E 25.00 26.64 23.67
4: Mono        F 24.21 26.60 28.32
5: Mono        G 29.44 29.39 26.11
6: Mono        P 25.20 26.44 23.87
7: Mono        R 32.28 31.91 33.58
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pivoting, you could group and summarize:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Poly, Subclass) %>%
  summarise(suppressWarnings(as_tibble(t(MVal))), .groups = "drop") %>%
  rename_with(~gsub("V", "Mval_", .x))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#>   Poly  Subclass Mval_1 Mval_2 Mval_3
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Di    F          21.8   18.2   20.3
#> 2 Di    G          21.2   19.3   22.0
#> 3 Mono  E          25     26.6   23.7
#> 4 Mono  F          24.2   26.6   28.3
#> 5 Mono  G          29.4   29.4   26.1
#> 6 Mono  P          25.2   26.4   23.9
#> 7 Mono  R          32.3   31.9   33.6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(MVal = c(29.44, 29.39, 26.11, 24.21, 26.6, 28.32, 
32.28, 31.91, 33.58, 25, 26.64, 23.67, 25.2, 26.44, 23.87, 21.21, 
19.3, 21.97, 21.79, 18.16, 20.3), Poly = c("Mono", "Mono", "Mono", 
"Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", 
"Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Mono", "Di", "Di", "Di", "Di", "Di", 
"Di"), Subclass = c("G", "G", "G", "F", "F", "F", "R", "R", "R", 
"E", "E", "E", "P", "P", "P", "G", "G", "G", "F", "F", "F")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: instead of tibble with warnings etc why not just `df%>%
    summarise(MVal=list(MVal),.by=c(Poly, Subclass)) %>% 
    unnest_wider(MVal, names_sep = "_")` if using `summarise`?

Comment: @onyambu that's a nice solution. Post as an answer? You need a separate `group_by` though, since the `.by` argument won't work in that case.

Comment: .by will definitely work here. Try it out

Comment: @onyambu I did. It didn't. Maybe I need to update dplyr